# MutableList<Any> addAll kotlin entire arraylist added as object

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, any, mutablelist

Following is my code

```
var items : MutableList<Any> = arrayListOf()
        items.add(TeacherDetails(it?.photo,it?.firstName,it?.lastName,it?.level))
        items.add(TeacherBio(it?.bio))
        items.add(TitleAccreditations(getString(R.string.acreditations)))
        items.add(SessionsTitle(it?.firstName + getString(R.string.apostrophe) + getString(
                        R.string.sessions)))
        items.addAll(listOf(it?.classes ?: arrayListOf()))
        items.add(IntroVideo(it?.introVideo))
        items.addAll(it?.teachingAccreditations?.split("\n")?.map { Accreditation(
            it
        ) }?: emptyList())
```

Issue is at following line it is adding entire list as object instead of individual item.

```
items.addAll(listOf(it?.classes ?: arrayListOf()))
```

Following is my model

```
data class Teacher(

@field:SerializedName("firstName")
val firstName: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("lastName")
val lastName: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("teacherId")
val teacherId: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("introVideo")
val introVideo: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("level")
val level: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("teachingAccreditations")
val teachingAccreditations: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("classes")
val classes: List<ClassesItem?>? = null,

@field:SerializedName("photo")
val photo: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("bio")
val bio: String? = null
)
```

Comment: can you add your `it` model code ?

Comment: added model code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess because your `type` of `list` is `Any`, it will consider adding `list` instance also as an `object`, so instead it as `listOf()` just add directly

```
items.addAll(it?.classes?.filterNotNull()?: arrayListOf())
```